# Why am I receiving the message: Incompatible: User Bower Instead when installing JQuery 3.5.1 in VS2019

Tags: jquery, nuget, bower, visual-studio-2019

When attempting to install the Jquery packages via NuGet, I receive the message Incompatible: Use Bower instead.  Bower is deprecated.  This was a bug in VS2017 and was reported as fixed.  It has raised its ugly head again in VS2019.

Anyone know of a way around this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try installing lower level Jquery version e.g. 3.4.1 or may be just 3.4?

Comment: I see Microsoft has this marked as fixed and closed for VS2017 in 2018 but I am running the latest version of VS2017 in 2021 and I see this message when I look at upgrading the bootstrap nuget package for 2 of 4 projects in my solution - oddly nuget seems happy enough to upgrade a third project (from: 3.0.0 to 4.6.0). Confusing.